# How to import React-Native types via Typescript for Flow?

Tags: typescript, react-native, flowtype, typechecking, flow-typed

In my react-native application I have a `TextInput` component. The `TextInput` reads some types from the following path:

```
/Users/karl/Library/Caches/typescript/3.6/node_modules/@types/react-native/index.d.ts
```

This file has a bunch of types in including:

```
export type KeyboardType = 'default' | 'email-address' | 'numeric' | 'phone-pad';
```

I can access this file by `cmd + clicking` on a prop I have added, (using vscode) to go to it's definition.

What I am wondering though is how I can reference the types in this file, so I can use them in my Flow typing definitions?

I want to be able to do something like:

```js
// pseudocode
import type { KeyboardType } from 'react-native'
```

How I can go about this?

Comment: Actually I've same issue and leave an answer for `flow-typed` and `typescript` both. I leave an upvote to your awesome post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing everything right, except you don't need the word `type` after `import`:

```
import { Image, StyleSheet, ReturnKeyType, KeyboardType } from "react-native";
```

Comment: Wow. It really is Monday. Thank you 

Comment: I actually now get this `Flow(InferError)`. But it's typed absolutely fine. Any ideas? `Cannot import 'KeyboardType' because there is no 'KeyboardType' export in 'react-native'. Flow(InferError)`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for `flow-typed` you should directly add the types from component source:

```js
import type {
  KeyboardType,
  ReturnKeyType,
} from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/TextInput/TextInput';
```

But for `typescript` first, install `@types/react-native` and then get all the types from `react-native`;

```js
import type { ReturnKeyType, KeyboardType } from 'react-native';
```